# stop on change function for one element in form

Tags: jquery

So I have this function that if anything changes in the form, it submits the form via the submit button.
I want to do this, but I want to exclude one element in the form. Its a checkbox with ID of "dogs". If  a user checks that, I dont want it to run this function even though it is in the form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#MainForm').change(function(){                
           $('#submit').click();
        });
    });
```

I tried this...

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#MainForm').not("#dogs").change(function(){               
           $('#submit').click();
        });
    });
```

It didn't work though and it still submitted the form when I clicked the checkbox, not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using the bubbling change event to know to submit the form.  If you want to ignore one element, you could prevent it's bubbling.

```
$('#dogs').on('change', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```js
$('#MainForm').on('change', function(){
  console.log('submit the form!');
});

$('#dogs').on('change', function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="MainForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cats" id="cats">
  <input type="checkbox" name="dogs" id="dogs">
</form>
```

Comment: So odd, still not working. When I click that checkbox, the page submits.

Comment: Does the snippet here, on the site, function as you would expect?  @TaLeNT_

Comment: Nevermind, your answer is working now. I had a typo.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#MainForm input').not("#dogs").change(function(){               
       $('#submit').click();
    });
});
```

You want to detect a change of the input, and then ignore the `#dogs` input. Your current version checks for a change of the `#MainForm` (which will always be true).

Comment: my main form has tons of elements though, checkboxs, radios and other input. I just want to exclude #dogs input. So do I need to use #Mainform input radio checkbox ?

Comment: You could just do `#Mainform *` then. But also note that radios and checkboxes are just inputs of a certain type. Selects, and textareas are an exception to that.

Comment: Use `#Mainform :input` The `:input` pseudo-selector` matches all type of user inputs.

Comment: But be aware that is jQuery specific syntax

Comment: when I use * #dogs still ends up submitting the form when checked, when I use :input all my other drop down and radio buttons on change do not work.

Comment: Don't use `* #dogs`, use `#MainForm *` and `#dogs`.

Comment: I was using $('#MainForm *').not("#dogs").change(function()